# How to programmatically check LOVE2D version

Tags: lua, versioning, love2d

How would one go about making sure that a .love file only runs if the current version of LOVE2D is better than a given minimum version? Without some sort of check, the resulting errors can be obscure and seemingly unrelated to the LOVE version, requiring the user to waste a lot of time trying to diagnose issues based on misleading errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `t.version = "0.8.0"` to your `conf.lua` and it will warn the user if he is using a version other than 0.8.0. You shouldn't *block* mismatched versions, you should *warn* them.

Here's an example of `conf.lua`:

```
function love.conf(t)
    t.title = "Game title"
    t.author = "Your name"
    t.version = "0.8.0"
end
```

[Here](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.conf)'s the wiki article on `conf.lua`.